# Moving existing RAIDed drives to new DataTale enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid

I have 4 2TB hard drives from a Mac Pro that were RAID 5'ed. I sold the Mac Pro but kept the hard drives. I just bought a DataTale 4-bay RAID enclosure that supports RAID 5 (http://oyendigital.com/hard-drives/store/RC-M4QJ.html). I'm not quite sure however how to have it "recognize" that they are already RAIDed and just continue using them.

Comment: Do you want to just start using the disks anew without keeping the data stored there or do you want to keep the data? Initializing RAID disks and discarding the stored data is a normal procedure while moving disks from one RAID implementation to another with keeping the data is usually almost impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Raid5 is not a protocol standard. Dont expect to be able to migrate between vendors. Sorry.